# XSL Perform sort not working on attributes?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

In the MWE below I have a sequence of attributes, which I sort, and then both output the XML and the attribute. When I output the entire XML it looks sorted:

```
<data attr="attrA">testA</data><data attr="attrZ">testZ</data> 
<data attr="attrZ">testZ</data><data attr="attrA">testA</data>
```

However if I print next the attributes, I do not get the sorted output (ascending == descending):

```
attrZ attrA
attrZ attrA
```

**How is this possible?**  How can I get:

```
attrA attrZ 
attrZ attrA
```

??

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
     <xsl:variable name="dataUnsorted" as="element()*">
            <data attr="attrZ">testZ</data>
            <data attr="attrA">testA</data>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="dataAscending" as="element()*">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="$dataUnsorted">
        <xsl:sort select="@attr" order="ascending"/> 
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="dataDescending" as="element()*">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="$dataUnsorted">
        <xsl:sort select="@attr" order="descending"/> 
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>  

     <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:message>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$dataAscending"/>
      </xsl:message> 
      <xsl:message>
           <xsl:copy-of select="$dataDescending"/>
      </xsl:message> 
      <xsl:message>
          <xsl:value-of select="$dataAscending/@attr"/>
      </xsl:message> 
      <xsl:message>
           <xsl:value-of select="$dataDescending/@attr"/>
      </xsl:message> 
      </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The step `/@attr` in `$dataAscending/@attr` selects the attribute nodes and sorts them in document order, that is how a step selecting nodes is defined (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-path-operator).

If you want to preserve the order you have three options:

1. Use a `for in return` expression: `for $e in $dataAscending return $e/@attr`
2. Sort and store the attribute sequence instead of the element sequence
3. XPath/XSLT 3+ only: use `!`: `$dataAscending!@attr`